# How to check if the TextField contains only characters

Tags: java, swing

In the code below, I need to know if the text held by the JTextField contains only characters or if it also contains numeric entries.

```
ResultSet rs= ItemQuery.findItem(jTextfield1.getText());
while(rs.next()){
    i_name =rs.getString(2);
    jLabel5.setText(i_name);
    currStock = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(3));
    jLabel6.setText(currStock);
    date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(rs.getDate(4));                
    jLabel8.setText(date);
}
```

Comment: `if(Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", str))` checks if `str` contains only letters.

Comment: It often helps to make your question more descriptive, to tell us a little bit more about your problem. A little effort in asking your question goes a long way towards helping us help you.

Comment: I see -- you had some question buried in comments. Please avoid that since most will miss seeing it. I only saw it because I edited your question to improve the readability of your code.

Comment: while using a swing component and or any intention to do something with it, it is rather better asking `hi, i want to do this things, which swing thingy will do that for me?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to find any digits or any thing else other than characters.

```
flag=1;
for (int i=0;i++;i<string.size()){
   if (!Character.isLetter(string.charat(i))){
        flag=0;
        break;
   }
}

 if (flag==0)
  // control enters this if statement when any thing other than letters is encountered in the string
```